# Auto-populating field from another feature layer in Survey123 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I'm creating a survey where the collector can drop a point and several fields auto-populate from another feature layer. For example, an inspector is at a property and finds a code violation. Hence, they drop a point, and the parcel ID, owner, and owner's mailing address auto-populates from the county parcel feature layer. I've read up on using JavaScript and pulldata() and have put together a script based on a template in Survey123.

```
function featureByLocation(location) {
// Output value.  Initially set to an empty string (XLSForm null)
let outValue = "";

// Check to make sure both layerURL and location are provided
if (layerURL == null || layerURL === "" || location == null || location === "") {
    // The function can't go forward; exit with the empty value
    return location;
}

// The coordinates will come in as `<lat> <lon> <alt> <acc>`.  
// We need <lon>,<lat> for the query
// Note that I'm using the relatively new ` ` string that lets me place variables ${var}
let coordsArray = location.split(" ");
let coords = `${coordsArray[1]},${coordsArray[0]}`;

var layerURL = 
Feature Service REST Endpoint   

// Set up query parameters
let f = "f=json";
let geometry = `geometry=${coords}`; 
let geometryType = "geometryType=esriGeometryPoint";
let inSR = "inSR=4326";
let spatialRel = "spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects";
let outFields = "outFields=*";
let returnGeometry = "returnGeometry=false";
let returnCount = "returnCount=1";
let parameters = [f,geometry,geometryType,inSR,spatialRel,outFields,returnGeometry,returnCount].join("&");
let url = `${layerURL}/query?${parameters}`;

// Create the request object
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Make the request.  Note the 3rd parameter, which makes this a synchronous request
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.send();


// Process the result
if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        // The http request did not succeed
        return "bad request: " + url
    } else {
            // Parse the response into an object
        let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.error) {
            // There was a problem with the query
        } else {
            if (response.features[0]) {
                outValue = JSON.stringify(response.features[0]);
            } else {
                // No features found
            }
        }
    }
}
return outValue;
```

My output generates the following below:

[image: Survey123 Output]

How could I include the Parcel ID, Owner, and Mailing address?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar. Your code works great except that the outValue is a stringified JSON object, where you probably want to pass an attribute value to your survey field not the whole JSON.

Here's what I changed, in my case I'm looking for the attribute field named DISTRICT:

```
if (response.features[0]) {
              outValue = response.features[0].attributes.DISTRICT;
```

If that doesn't work, check your REST query and make sure it is written correctly and is set to output JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit off-topic, please note that you can save yourself some time if you consider using Javascript, that Javascript functions are disabled when used outside your organisation or used on a public (non-login) survey.